# AlertDialog.Builder item background color

Tags: android

I'm trying to make the three items of this AlertDialog green. The problem is that currently a green background appears behind the alert, and two of the items do not appear green. I currently set the style of the AlertDialog with this code:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.ListRow));
```

In my styles.xml, I have this style:

```
<style name="ListRow">
    <item name="android:background">@color/forest_green</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dialog_text</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: What is your problem with this code anyway?

Comment: Don't use `android:background` on a *theme*. Everything that doesn't define its background will be green. How about you override `android:buttonBarStyle` and `android:buttonBarButtonStyle` instead?

Comment: You may take a look at these tutorials: http://blog.supenta.com/2014/07/02/how-to-style-alertdialogs-like-a-pro/ and http://www.materialdoc.com/alerts/

Answer (score 0):

you can set custom view programmatically like this way..

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, (ViewGroup) getCurrentFocus());
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(dialoglayout);
builder.show();
```

create dialog_layout.xml in your layouts with green background.

Answer (score 0):

this worked to me. all of them have background.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.ListRow));

builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info).setTitle("welcome")
        .setMessage("...")
        .setPositiveButton("login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("register", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the dialog style with `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert` as parent:

```
 <style name="AlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Source: http://www.materialdoc.com/alerts/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    final AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AppTheme)).create();
```

add the buttons; and

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 2;i++) {
        Button b = ad.getButton(i);
        b.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
    ad.show();
```

change your theme and color.

Answer (score -1):

Use  styles.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I have use this getting error :                     error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/AlertDialog'.